# extrior product of a square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, multilinear-algebra

I want to understand how one can find the exterior product of square matrices. I searched about it and I find a lot of complicated formulas and without any examples. On the other hand, I found [this anwser](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604461/action-of-a-matrix-on-the-exterior-algebra/1605226) that contains a nice example. What I understood from the example is the new matrix ( I meant the exterior product one) comes from the determinant of minors of the original matrices. I want to know whether we have a similar thing for the higher-dimensional case.

Let me ask my questions better, 1) Does one can calculate the exterior product of square matrices by calculating minors of the original one? 2)Let $A$ be a $5 \times 5$ matrix. Can one give a concrete example that calculates $\wedge^3 A$?
Thanks in advance

Comment: The answer to (1) is yes. On [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3957275/81360), I provide a proof of the formula for the entries of the matrix associated with $\wedge^2 A$, but this proof can be extended to higher exterior powers as well.

Comment: Regarding (2): you're asking us to compute a $10 \times 10$ matrix. Is there another approach we could take here? Would you be satisfied with a python script that computes this matrix?

Comment: @BenGrossmann : Thank you very much for your comments. Yes, A python script is great.

Comment: @BenGrossmann I would really appreciate it if you could email it to me; adamrt88@gmail.com